# AJAX Response not working in FF

Tags: ajax, firefox

I have a bit of code which alerts the $response from a php code in IE, but for some reason it doesn't work in FF..

Here's the code:

```
function contactfunction() {
  var url = "scripts/php/cbb.php?pname=";
  xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = updatecontact1;
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function updatecontact1() {
  if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
    var response = xmlHttp.responseText;
    alert(response);
  }
}
```

And here's the PHP file (cbb.php)

```
<?php
$fp=fopen("ip.txt","a+");
fwrite($fp, "cib\r\n");
fclose($fp);  
$response = "something";
return $response;
?>
```

Can anyone help me out here? I'm not sure how to get it to work in FF, it just gives a blank popup..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do yourself a favour, and use one of the many ajax capable Javascript libraries out there, like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), which frees the user from hacking up code to deal with browser discrepancies (for the most part, at least):

```
//using jQuery's $.get method
function update(name) {
    $.get('cbb.php?name=' + name, function(response) {
        alert(response);
        $('#someDiv').html(response);
    });
}
```

or:

```
//using jQuery's $.load method
function update(name) {
    //directly inject div id="someDiv" with output of url
    $('#someDiv').load('cbb.php?name=' + name);
}
```

Putting it together:

```
//when the DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function() {

    //bind to click event of all anchors with class="contact"
    $('a.contact').click(function(e) {

        //stop the link from being followed
        e.preventDefault(); 

        //get the name from the link text
        var name = $(this).text();
        update(name);
    });

});

<a href="no-script.php" class="contact">Timmy</a>
<a href="no-script.php" class="contact">McLovin</a>

<div id="someDiv">This is where the output will be injected</div>
```

See http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax for more information.

Comment: Yeh I know, I think jQuery is easier, but was told it HAD to be ajax.. *sigh* I managed to work it out, but thank you, will use this if I have to do it again :)

Comment: ajax is a built in functionality OF jQuery. that's what the .load() command is.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the code working by using:

```
function getFile(fileToOpen) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
        alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",fileToOpen,false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    alert( xmlhttp.responseText );
}

function contactfunction() {
    getFile('scripts/php/cbb.php?pname=');
}
```

If anyone else has the same problem :)